# How to get the cookie in javascript in cshtml page which was created in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have created the cookie having user login id when user logs out and want to get that user login id in login page to populate the login id text box.

But I am not getting the cookie value in login page javascript function.

My `logout` action in `homecontroller` is like this:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{  
    string loginId = SessionManager.UserloginId;      
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
    Session.clear();  
    Session.Abandon();  
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserLoginId");  
    cookie.value = loginId;  
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");  
}
```

And in Index.cshtml page my javascript code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jcookie = '@Request.Cookies["UserLoginId"].Value';   
$("#LogInId").val() = jcookie;
</script>
```

But I am not getting the loginId stored in the cookie, please help me with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set value using jQuery use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) instead of `$("#LogInId").val() = jcookie;`. So change your code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jcookie = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserLoginId"].Value';   
    $("#LogInId").val(jcookie);
</script>
```

Also, use `@HttpContext.Current.Request` instead of `@Request`

EDIT: As per comment

```
can u please tell me now how to set the value of this UserLoginId value to = ""(I mean blank) after i assign value to $("#LogInId").val(jcookie);?
```

If you want to set `UserLoginId` cookie value to blank, why are you saving it in cookie. You can easliy do this using `TempData` like

In controller

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{  
    string loginId = SessionManager.UserloginId;      
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
    Session.clear();  
    Session.Abandon();  

    //Used here
    TempData["UserLoginId"] = loginId;  

    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");  
}
```

In Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jcookie = '@TempData["UserLoginId"]';   
    $("#LogInId").val(jcookie);
</script>
```

`TempData` value will be cleared after use

Comment: No.. I am getting '@Request.Cookies["userLoginId"].Value' itself as undefined

Comment: @vijayyaragall, I have updated answer, use `@HttpContext.Current.Request` instead of `@Request`

Comment: Ya tried    @ HttpContext.Current.Request instead of @Request.. still not able get the cookie value..

Comment: @Satpal.. can u please tell me now how to set the value of this UserLoginId value to = ""(I mean blank) after  i assign value to $("#LogInId").val(jcookie);?

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
<Script type="test/javascript">
 var jcookie = '@Request.Cookies["UserLoginId"].Value';   
$("#loginId").val(jcookie)
</Script>
```

Comment: I think it should be `$("#loginId").val(jcookie)`

Comment: No.. I am getting '@Request.Cookies["userLoginId"].Value' itself as undefined

Comment: may be coz u should make "u" capital in userLoginId