# Read a cookie values in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I'm creating cookie in my code behind like this

```
            HttpCookie objCookie = new HttpCookie("DefaultName");
            objCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
            objCookie.Values["Name"] = Name;
            objCookie.Values["Id"] = Id;
            Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie);
```

Now the question is how can i access values "Name" and "Id" in javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Below code read content in cookie

```
(function(){
    var cookies;

    function readCookie(name,c,C,i){
        if(cookies){ return cookies[name]; }

        c = document.cookie.split('; ');
        cookies = {};

        for(i=c.length-1; i>=0; i--){
           C = c[i].split('=');
           cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
        }

        return cookies[name];
    }

    window.readCookie = readCookie; // or expose it however you want
})();
```

Comment: you copied it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510291/how-to-get-the-cookie-in-javascript-in-cshtml-page-which-was-created-in-controll

Answer (score 0):

Simply,    `var _value = document.cookie;`

In general, if you have many values in cookies, just say it's comma separated,

```
var _cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(',');
```

Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var _value = $.cookie('Id'); //OR Name
alert(_value);
```